# SQL rotate results from wide to vertical

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would love some help with the best way to capture some column data and rotate it so I can store the column name and numeric value in a temp table.

The results are a single row showing a value for the columns listed here:

```
AccountingCode ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1 ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1Description
-------------- --------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
    0              71                                264
```

I would like to take the above query and rotate the output to look more vertical.

```
ColName                                          Value
--------------------------------------------- ---------
AccountingCode                                      0
ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1                  71
ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1Description      264
```

I was trying to use PIVOT / UNPIVOT but could not figure how to make it work for this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I was tring to use PIVOT / UNPIVOT ...".  So where's this query that you "tried"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with `SQL Sever` then you can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT tt.ColName, tt.val
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ('AccountingCode', AccountingCode), 
              ('ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1', ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1),
              ('ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1Description', ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1Description)    
     ) tt(ColName, Val);
```

In standard you can use `UNION ALL` to `UNPIVOT` the data.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, This was the nudge I needed.  I'm sorry I dont have enough rep to upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

The generic way in SQL is `UNION ALL`:

```
select 'AccountingCode', AccountingCode from t
union all
select 'ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1', ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1 from t
union all
select 'ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1Description', ActiveCostAllocationCode1Segment1Description
```

This assumes that the types of the columns are compatible (they all look like integers, so that is probably okay).

The better method is to use a lateral join (or `apply` in some databases), if your database supports it.